# Select specific date / hour range from list elements and create dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a list with approximately 150 elements (data frames) of weather data (ID,date,time,temperature). I want to select specific date range and time from each list element (df) and create a data frame (or multiple) with these selected rows. Given the fact I can't provide real data I've created a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

z1 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+780), by = "10 min")
z2 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+780), by = "10 min")
z3 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+780), by = "10 min")
z4 <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+780), by = "10 min")

temperature1 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature2 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature3 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature4 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)

station1 <- data.frame(date = z1, temp = temperature1)
station2 <- data.frame(date = z2, temp = temperature2)
station3 <- data.frame(date = z3, temp = temperature3)
station4 <- data.frame(date = z4, temp = temperature4)

##isolate date from time
station1 <- separate(station1, date, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
station2 <- separate(station2, date, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
station3 <- separate(station3, date, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
station4 <- separate(station4, date, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")

## list of all stations

stations_list <- list(station1,station2,station3,station4)

#create a column with station ID (name) ##
ID_names <- c("station1","station2","station3","station4")


stations_list <- mapply(cbind,stations_list, "ID" = ID_names, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Now in this list I want to select specific date and time range so I used the following script:

```
selected_date_time <- map_dfr(stations_list,
                              ~ filter(.x, date >= "2021-06-01" &
                                         date <= "2021-10-15" &  time >= "18:00" & time <= "10:00"  | 
                                         date > "2022-08-18" & date <= "2022-10-05" & time >= "09:00" 
                                       & time <= "17:00"))
```

In this case, I got a data frame with only 2022 year and no selection fro 2021. I changed slightly the code and I selected different hour range :

```
selected_date_time <- map_dfr(stations_list,
                              ~ filter(.x, date >= "2021-06-01" &
                                         date <= "2021-10-15" &  time >= "18:00" & time <= "10:00"  | 
                                         date > "2022-08-18" & date <= "2022-10-05" & time <= "09:00" 
                                       & time >= "17:00"))
```

In the last case I got a data frame with zero observations. What am I doing wrong ?!

Comment: 1) You have to add the relevant package in order to use `map_dfr`.
2) Your `date` and `time` columns are `character` and things like `date <= "2021-10-15"` or `time >= "18:00"` might not work as you expect them to work.

Comment: Also, is this `time >= "18:00" & time <= "10:00"` correct?
You might want to try to use parentheses before/after `|`. Something like `~filter(.x, (...&...&...) | (...&...&...))`

Comment: In practically any programming language if you mix AND and OR operators, always use parentheses.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. I corrected my code but unfortunately parenthesis wasn't the problem.  @AntoniosK  I had load the package purrr, but I forgot to copy & paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @AntoniosK, your filter logic was off so I made a few amendments but most importantly, for this filter to work, we need to make sure the date and time are "date" and "time" class respectively.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(tidyverse)
library(hms)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'hms'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hms

z1 <-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 780), by = "10 min")
z2 <-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 780), by = "10 min")
z3 <-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 780), by = "10 min")
z4 <-seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 780), by = "10 min")

temperature1 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature2 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature3 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)
temperature4 <- runif(112321, min = -5, max = 45)

station1 <- tibble(date = z1, temp = temperature1)
station2 <- tibble(date = z2, temp = temperature2)
station3 <- tibble(date = z3, temp = temperature3)
station4 <- tibble(date = z4, temp = temperature4)

station1 <- station1 %>%
  mutate(time = hms::as_hms(date),
         date = as_date(date)) %>%
  relocate(date, time)

station2 <- station2 %>%
  mutate(time = hms::as_hms(date),
         date = as_date(date)) %>%
  relocate(date, time)

station3 <- station3 %>%
  mutate(time = hms::as_hms(date),
         date = as_date(date)) %>%
  relocate(date, time)

station4 <- station4 %>%
  mutate(time = hms::as_hms(date),
         date = as_date(date)) %>%
  relocate(date, time)

## list of all stations

stations_list <- list(station1, station2, station3, station4)

#create a column with station ID (name) ##
ID_names <- c("station1", "station2", "station3", "station4")

stations_list <-
  mapply(cbind, stations_list, "ID" = ID_names, SIMPLIFY = F)

stations_list %>%
  map_dfr(~ filter(
    .x,
    (
      between(date, as.Date("2021-06-01"), as.Date("2021-10-15")) &
        (time >= as_hms("18:00:00") | time <= as_hms("10:00:00"))
    ) |
      (date > as.Date("2022-08-18") &
         date <= as.Date("2022-10-05")) &
      (time <= as_hms("09:00:00") | time >= as_hms("17:00:00"))
  )) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  head()
#>         date     time      temp       ID
#> 1 2021-06-01 00:00:00 20.259581 station1
#> 2 2021-06-01 00:10:00 37.558833 station1
#> 3 2021-06-01 00:20:00 18.729679 station1
#> 4 2021-06-01 00:30:00  5.880394 station1
#> 5 2021-06-01 00:40:00  2.393515 station1
#> 6 2021-06-01 00:50:00 36.030296 station1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Desmond, thank you very much for the answer and for your time. The remarks you made in my code are very interesting and I will keep them in mind, but your code as you can see in the head() , it didn't work as it should. The output is exactly the data I had, without any filter. More specifically, the first row in the output it should have been :  1  2021-06-01 00:10:00   12.183567 station1, instead it is:  1 2021-05-26 08:00:00 12.183567 station1

Comment: Thanks for flagging that. I was missing some parentheses in my filter logic. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Desmond for your immediate answer. It  worked! Thanks for your time and effort to help!